# Multiple Operations with FileInputStream

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I have a Java class to read a file and set some data to a class. I have a class

**FileMetadata.java**

```
public class FileMetadata implements Serializable {

    private String location;
    private Double size;
    private String content;
    private List<String> lines;
    private String md5Digest;

    //parameterized constructor
    //getters and setters
}
```

After reading the file, I want to set the values in this class.

This is my method to read the file.

**FileUtil.java**

```
public static void readFile(File file) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    List<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbLine = new StringBuilder();
        int ch;
        while ((ch = fis.read()) != -1) {
            String line = "" + (char) ch;
            sb.append(line);
            if(line.matches("(\r|\n)")) {
                fileLines.add(sbLine.toString());
                sbLine.setLength(0);
            } else {
                sbLine.append(line);
            }
        }
        String md5 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(fis);
        System.out.println(md5);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        System.out.println(getFileSizeInKB(file));
        for(String str : fileLines) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But the list is not coming up properly as it is adding an empty string after each line, because the file next line is **"\r\n"**. The second time it is adding empty StringBuilder so the list is getting extra empty string after each line. 
I could try checking the length of it before adding to List. But if the file contains an empty line, I want to add to the list.

Comment: As a general rule, it's not safe to reuse Streams.  Create a new input stream for new operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `BufferedReader` class.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
 ..............
}
br.close();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
String md5 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(fis);
fis.close();
```

(There is not exception handling in the example).

Comment: But then how about Getting the FileMD5? it needs InputStream

Comment: Hi, you can create another Stream after reading the File. I'll update the answer with it.